How to use ngx-cookie-service-ssr in Angular 19 with SSR
I'm trying to setup ngx-cookie-service-ssr for my project. However, in the set up description,
It's mentioned that I have to replace this code in the server.ts
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
});


with this
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, {
    req,
    providers: [
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl },
      { provide: 'REQUEST', useValue: req },
      { provide: 'RESPONSE', useValue: res },
    ],
  });
});

I could not find it since Angular has changed the structure of the server.ts in Angular 19.

I looked at the commit on ngx-cookie-ssr that introduces the Angular 19 support - "feat(core): adds angular 19 support (#329) #331". The update simply bumps the versions of Angular dependencies in package.json (I assume is just to have something enough that we avoid needing the --legacy-peer-deps flag during npm install) and just adds the version 19 on the table in the Readme.
The PR doesn't really update how SsrCookieService should read cookies on the server side. It currently is still the same, using its own custom DI InjectionToken<Request>('REQUEST') and expecting it to work. This by the way also does not work on Angular 18 ng serve, but works fine if you just keep using build prod during development (Refer here).
As for Angular 19, I suggest just implementing your own CookieService, inspired from the SsrCookieService. Just replace the custom DI with the new REQUEST injection token that is native to Angular 19. Notice that CookeService has a property documentIsAccessible which is just a isPlatformBrowser check. Implement the same idea and just access the document directly if you are on browser runtime. On the server runtime, use the new REQUEST from @angular/core to get the cookie.
Just a heads up, making sure to check if you are on server runtime is not enough to safely read cookies from the REQUEST. Make sure you have handled all of these conditions where null is expected:


During the build processes.
When the application is rendered in the browser (client-side rendering).
When performing static site generation (SSG).
During route extraction in development (at the time of the request).


Especially the first case, "During route extraction in development (at the time of the request)". See this issue: AngularNodeAppEngine: Injected REQUEST empty on first initialization #28995
